# Is there any difference between the three assignment ways: a=1, let a=1, ((a=1))

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Consider the three ways to assign a value:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=1
let a=1
((a=1))
```

Are the three assignments totally equal?

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu bash

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your shell has non-POSIX extensions (ie. ksh or bash), they're entirely equivalent: `a=1` is a string assignment, whereas `let a=1` and `(( a=1 ))` are numeric assignments, but what gets stored in `a` is a string representing the number `1` in every case.

`$(( ))` is the POSIX-compliant way to create a math context. `(( ))` and `let`, by contrast, are *not* specified by POSIX, but are extensions available in some shells that go beyond the standard.

---

Now, consider instead:

```
b=2

         # result  | posix?  | type               | comments
         # --------+---------+--------------------+----------------
a=b      # a=b     | true    | string assignment  |
let a=b  # a=2     | false   | numeric assignment | ancient non-POSIX syntax
a=$((b)) # a=2     | true    | numeric assignment | modern POSIX syntax
((a=b))  # a=2     | false   | numeric assignment | modern non-POSIX extension
```

Comment: The example in the last part is very useful, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For the given operands they are identical. However, `let` has a couple of additional features beyond simple assignment. First, the right-hand side of the assignment is treated in an arithmetic context. Compare

```
$ a=1+1; echo $a
1+1
$ let a=1+1; echo $a
2
```

Further, as a command, the arguments to `let` are processed by the shell prior to the assignment, letting you declare a parameter dynamically.

```
$ a=b
$ let $a=5
$ echo $b
5
```

The same is true for `$((...))` or `((...))`:

```
$ a=b
$ : $(( $a = 5 ))  # or (( $a = 5))
$ echo $b
5
```

And as with any command argument, special characters need to be quoted:

```
$ let "a = 3 * 5"; echo $a
15
```

This does not apply to `$(( ... ))` or `(( ... ))`, though.

```
$ a=$(( 3 * 5 ))
$ (( a = 3 * 5 ))
```

Comment: Claiming that these features are exclusive to let, rather than available in any math context, is a touch misleading.